# Django and Gunicorn - Gateway time-out for loop

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to setup a Django project inside a 1GB Digital Ocean droplet. One critical function of the project is to import data from .ods files.

When testing the project with the Django development server `manage.py runserver` (already inside the droplet) I can import a quite big number of rows - up to 20000 with no problems and without eating the server's memory as the loop that iterates the ods file sleeps 2 seconds every 100 rows.

But when using Gunicorn (alongside with nginx), only 20 to 30 rows are processed, on average. After that I'm getting Gateway time-out 504 code errors.

I already tried with no result:

- Increasing the --timeout of the gunicorn workers
- Installing `eventlet` and using `--worker-class eventlet` in the workers
- Upgrading my droplet to a 4GB Ram / 2 Cpus plan and increasing to `--workers 6`

This is how a simplified version of the code looks like:

```
    table = read(path_to_ods_file)
    stop_every_rows = 100
    rows_done = 0
    stop_seconds = 1

    for i in range(len(table)):
      Profile.objects.create(
        first_name=table[i][0],
        last_name=table[i][0],
      )

      rows_done += 1
      if rows_done >= stop_every_rows:
          rows_done = 0
          time.sleep(stop_seconds)
```

Something really weird is that most of the times not even a single user is created.

This is how my gunicorn service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=app_4
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/app_4/backend
ExecStart=/home/app_4/backend/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet     --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/app_4/backend/project/backend$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you have some additional data for user ? You can't create user with only first_name & last_name. You have to provide email, username, password as well

Comment: @Madi7 it's just a simplfied version of the code. I'll update the example so doesn't confuses anyone.

Comment: Does the import of the .ods files have to happen within a HTTP request/response cycle? Could the import instead be triggered by running a Django management command manually?

Comment: @WillKeeling it should be triggered somehow by the final user from the browser, and it should return the confirmation that the rows were processed. I've the idea of who this could work with another architecture design but in this case the application is so little (and will be used only in a couple of events) the just by increasing the time out should be fine, but this is not working as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haved tried `gunicorn`. Then I suggest tuning the `Nginx`.

Add your `conf` by [this](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/)

```
  proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;
```